# Eigenvector centrality JAVA

Tags: java, matrix, eigenvector, eigenvalue

I am trying to find the dominant Eigenvector of an adjacency matrix in JAVA.

I already have a function to calculate the dominant EigenValue, though I am told that in order to calculate the EigenVEctor of that one EigenValue, I have to find the solution of the equation Ax = λx (being A the adjacency matrix and λ the dominant eigenvalue).

So I subtract the EigenValue from the adjacency matrix. Then, I was also told to use the Gauss method to find the vector. Though I have no clue on how to do this.

Let's say, my A is:

```
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 1 0 1
1 0 0 0
```

Let's say the dominant EigenValue is 2,10 (it isn't). I subtract that value from the matrix's diagonal:

```
-2.10 1 0 0
0 -2.10 1 0
0 1 -2.10 1
1 0 0 -2.10
```

I use the gauss method and then I don't have any idea on what to do with that result.

I don't want to use any library to do this, as I want to do this using algebrical ways.

Comment: What's the math behind it?